# Firebase emulator not shutting down gracefully to save data

Tags: firebase, command-line-interface, emulation, firebase-tools

I installed firebase-tools-instant-win.exe for my flutter app. it works fine after configuring it. However I can't use the

```
emulators:start --export-on-exit=./saved-data
```

to save the database locally because when I Ctrl+C, it doesn't shutdown gracefully. There is no message that it shutting down and saving just a ^V

I also get the message that there are multiple instances of the emulator running. I notice the port assigned moves every restart on the (emulator)
browser console: localhost:4000, then 4001 etc...

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing, did you every figure out how to get it to export before shutting down? I'm using:

firebase emulators:start --import=./data --export-on-exit

Comment: @JeffNeet unfortunately no, ended up removing the emulator and just used firebase directly instead of wasting time trying to make it work